# Regex to match space followed by one or more character

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to break down a string into three lines. Each line should be formed by a word, not a character.

For exmaple:

```
G G YELLOW/WHITE CORN
```

must return

```
G G
YELLOW/WHITE
CORN.
```

So far I have:

```
String[] spitted= sentence.split("[a-zA-Z]{2,}",3);
```

it returns:

```
 G G 
 /
 CORN
```

I think my solution is to use a regular expession to match a space followed by a word, not a character, but I'm not good at regexp.

The laguage I'm using is java.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave more examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting:

```
\s+(?=\S{2})
```

Which means split on 1 or more space followed by at least 2 or more non-space characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR8lC9/1)

For Java use:

```
String[] spitted = sentence.split("\\s+(?=\\S{2})");
```

Comment: This is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Yes indeed `(?=...)` is positive lookahead